# Posting data to a webform through JQuery and diplaying the posted page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http

I have a long data to pass, Hence I have chosen post method to pass data.
I used `$.post("webform2.aspx",{data:message})` in webform1.aspx's button click.
After it is posted I could not see webform2.aspx rendered. It still stays in webform1.aspx

Any way to pass the data and display the posted page.

Comment: Got answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `ajax post` .You can't redirected to new page that you have posted.

If you will use `Ajax post` ,you have to manually replace the result that you got by the `ajax post` in current page.

I give here simple example of `Ajax Post`

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
$( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Comment: oh yes. you are right. Is there a possibility to post the data and redirect from scripts , like we do with postbackurl property in asp buttons.

Comment: Tell me the requirement of your situation.then only i can tell u wich solution is better

Comment: Your answer is very relevant to the question. However to solve this is discussed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit and I solved it with that. Thanks for your help. To know more about my requirement, I Fetch data from a webservice and then post the data to a new page. So i needed a redirection + posting. I preferred post than GET because its a long data having special symbols.